# debian: control file add dependency on the current building version

Tags: packaging, deb

I'm building a number of packages from one source package, I'd like one of my packages to depend on another package *explicitly* on the version that is being built and no-other - ie the current version being built.

```
Depends: original-package-min (= "what do I put here"),
```

I suspect there's an obvious answer, but I'm not finding it anywhere.

Background:

I'm trying to split a package into two, a minimal and a full version - something like this.  The `-min` package exists because when building for a new distribution there can be circular (runtime) dependencies.

```
Package: original-package-min
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}
Description: Minimal version of original package
 Useful when bootstrapping new or incomplete distributions

Package: original-package
Architecture: all
Depends: original-package-min (= "what do I put here"),
 # lots of dependencies missing
 ${misc:Depends}
Description: Original package
 Does what the original package does
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue is knowing how to ask the right question.  The right question here is "what can I put inside `${}` in a debian control file"?

I expected to find the answer in the manual on [Declaring relationships between packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html), but I eventually found the reference to the [reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-substvars) to the [reference](https://linux.die.net/man/5/deb-substvars) [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#source-package-control-files-debian-control):

> The fields here may contain variable references - their values will be substituted by dpkg-gencontrol, dpkg-genchanges or dpkg-source when they generate output control files. See Variable substitutions: debian/substvars for details.

To find the available substitutions simply run:

```
man deb-substvars
```

In this case the answer is

```
Depends: original-package-min (= ${binary:Version}),
```

It's possible `${source:Version}` could also be appropriate according to the document they are the same, except in specific instances where they are different.